# How to overlap panels in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, overlay, layout-manager

I have a screen in my application. The layout of the screen is shown in the attached image file.[image]

I have to add upto 5 labels in **Panel1111**. But, When I try to add labels in **Panel1111**, the **Panel11** resizes and **Panel12** shifts downwards to give space to **Panel11**.

**I want to overlap content of Panel1111 on Panel12.**

How can I achieve it?

Layout details:

1. Panel1 : BorderLayout
2. Panel11: OverLayLayout
3. Panel111: GridBagLayout

Comment: use undecorated JDialog or JWindow instead of bothering with

Comment: Panel11 is kind of redundant isn't it? What happens when you get rid of Panel11?

Comment: *"But, When I try.."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JLayeredPane.  Go to Oracle Java website, and go through the tutorial: [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Answer (score 1):

Java's Layout Managers by default try to show all information that is inside them.
If you say you want two panels to overlap, this essentially means that the lower one cannot be seen fully, and also not interacted with in the hidden/overlapped part. Then, this part of the panel doesn't make sense any more. So you should probably rethink your GUI.

If you want it to overlap only at certain times, and the user can define when it should overlap and when not, then you'll need to handle that manually by using no Layout Manager at all, but position the elements yourself. Oracle provides some hints how to do that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html.
In the end, you might end up writing your own, custom Layout Manager to handle the resizing of the panels.

Note: only the the layout of Panel 1 must be manually managed. The other panels can likely be handled by a LayoutManager again.